# LINQ Query Issues when trying to select from empty collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query that is pulling a final resultset from 2 collections: `usersAd` and `usersWithSecurity`:

```
var results = from usrAd in usersAd
              from usrRepo in usersWithSecurity
                             .Where(x => usrAd.Value.ToLower() == x.Value.ToLower())
                             .DefaultIfEmpty()
      select new User(userRepository)
      {
        ID = usrRepo == null ? null : usrRepo.ID,
        Value = usrAd.Value,
        FullName = usrAd.FullName
      };
```

The problem is I keep getting the following error: `Value cannot be null.`

I know the issue is that the `usersWithSecurity` collection is empty. I added the '.DefaultIfEmpty()` on the end but it still produces the exception.

How can I modify my LINQ statement to go ahead and return *everything* from `usersAd` and items from `usersWithSecurity` if it exists and the values match (as shown in the lambda)?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - `ID` in this case is a `string`. Actually just to remove the doubt of the properties being the culprit, I just hardcoded `ID = "123"` and took everything else out and got the same error.

Comment: I suspect `DefaultIfEmpty` is the culprit. remove it. everything should be ok

Comment: @atconway - What are we using Linq with?  Is this Linq-to-Objects, NHibernate, EF, Linq-To-Sql, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var usersWithSecurity = _biz.getUsersWithSecurity() ?? new List<User>();

var results = from usrAd in usersAd
              from usrRepo in usersWithSecurity
              where usrAd.Value.ToLower() == usrRepo.Value.ToLower()
              select new User(userRepository)
              {
                  ID = usrRepo == null ? null : usrRepo.ID,
                  Value = usrAd.Value,
                  FullName = usrAd.FullName
              };
```

Comment: In this case since there is no lambda, the `x` in the `where` clause is undefined?

Comment: I changed `x` to `usrAd` and still have the same resulting error.

Comment: sorry, typo plus added `HasValue`

Comment: What does this do `usrRepo.Value.ToLower() == usrRepo.Value.ToLower()`? Does this makes any sense?

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: it's just a typo

Comment: `usersWithSecurity` is currently a `IEnumerable<User>` and `.HasValue` does not exist on it. It says `cannot resolve symbol .HasValue`

Comment: what is `Value`? Is that a property name or a Nullable?

Comment: `Value` is a property name. I have even gone back to removing all properties being assigned and just hardcoding 1 (`ID = "123"`) to simplify the query. It can't get past the fact that usersWithSecurity is null

Comment: if `usersWithSecurity` is null try using a null coalesce in the query or where you declare it

Comment: @hunter - That was it! I needed to initialize the `usersWithSecurity` return just as you showed (I had added it separtely and ole' ReSharper added in the coalesce :) ). One thing though I did have to do so all situations work is use the following line: `from usrRepo in usersWithSecurity.Where(x => usrAd.Value.ToLower() == x.Value.ToLower()).DefaultIfEmpty()` Having the where on the separate line or adding `DefaultIfEmpty()` afterwards didn't act like a left join and brought back nothing. If you want to modify your code example to use my `.Where()` or modify to make similar it matches mine!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `Value cannot be null` is the standard message from an `ArgumentNullException`.  If you're debugging, and you expand on the error message, you'll see the actual parameter name that is causing the argument null exception.

Are any of `usersAd`, `usersWithSecurity`, `userRepository` null?

EDIT:

Okay, with more information provided from you in your comment, I now see the issue.  `usersWithSecurity` is null, and it can't be.  The `source` parameter is the name for the source `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` in all of the extension methods found in the `Enumerable` and `Queryable` classes.

If you fix that, it should work as you expect, left join and all.

```
usersWithSecurity = usersWithSecurity ?? Enumerable.Empty<User>(); // or similar
```

Comment: @atconway - I completely changed my answer.  At the very least it might help you accurately pinpoint exactly where the error is happening.

Comment: Yes it says `Parameter name: source` but that doesn't indicate the true culprit. I added some brute logic to run a reduced version of the query if `usersWithSecurity` is `null` and it worked, but the query doesn't bring back all the needed results.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue certainly occurs when you are performing your `.ToLower()` on an empty var. I recommend to avoid hidden string allocations within a loop (in your case, within your `Where`). Instead, use `String.Compare()`.

Here is an example using your code.

```
var results = from usrAd in usersAd
      from usrRepo in usersWithSecurity.Where(x => string.Equals(usrAd.Value, x.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      select new User(userRepository)
      {
        ID = usrRepo == null ? null : usrRepo.ID,
        Value = usrAd.Value,
        FullName = usrAd.FullName
      };
```

Comment: I tried this and I get `Cannot convert type 'int' to return type 'bool'`. I think this is because the lambda expression expects the predicate to return a `bool`

Comment: Yes you are right. I edited my code in order to return a `bool`.

Comment: Nope, if value is null It will throw `NullReferenceException` not `ArgumentNullException`

Comment: The syntax is now fine but it produces the same resulting error. I have even gone back to removing all properties being assigned and just hardcoding 1 to simplify the query. It's can't get past the fact that `usersWithSecurity` is `null`

Comment: @AustinSalonen Your link is broken

Comment: For reference... `String.Compare` is used to return an int of either -1, 0, or 1 to refer to greater than, less than, or equal scenarios.  If you just want to test for equality, you are much better off using `String.Equals(str1, str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` as an example, which simply returns a bool.

Comment: @atconway You answered your own question by the way.  `usersWithSecurity` cannot be null.  It's expecting an IEnumerable<User>.  Before you call the LINQ query you must make sure that `usersWithSecurity` is assigned.  If it's empty, make it an empty enumerable with the statement `usersWithSecurity = Enumerable.Empty<User>();`